# Is it possible to set the background color for the tag i created in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So, i need to show different tags on the post page. Is there any js hacks maybe? Is it even possible?

Comment: yes,you can add color.

Comment: Use CSS, I'm pretty sure, that each tag has it's own class.